# The Stanley Parable Demo not launching on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, steam

I installed the Stanley Parable Demo and Steam because I think it's an amazing game but whenever I click play, the game doesn't launch. I researched this issue but I couldn't find anything. If someone can help, that would be cool.

I have launched Stanley in the terminal and got:

```
'/home/adam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Demo/stanley_linux' 
/home/adam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable Demo/stanley_linux: error while loading shared libraries: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you run Steam from the Terminal and try to launch the game, you could see some error messages in the Terminal. Please paste them here.

Comment: The problem isn’t that steam doesn’t launch it’s just The Stanley Parable.

Comment: I recently launched The Stanley Parable in the terminal. I posted what I got in the question.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by browsing the game files, opening the file named bin, and renaming lipstd++.so.6 to BADlibstdc++.so.6

Comment: Wow, this actually worked for me!  What's the reasoning behind this?  Thank you very much.  :)

Comment: @MichaelWehar Steam games bundle some libraries they think the target system will not have. In this case, the bundled libraries have become old and are not needed anymore. Removing / renaming it allows the library on the target system to be used, and everything works again!